# choosing between two tables in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, case

Question for you - not sure if it is feasible however.

I have a scenario where I want to SELECT a set of data from one table if it exists there then if it doesn't I want to SELECT it from a different table where I know it will exist.  The issue is they have slightly different field names in some cases.  I am curious if a CASE clause would be the best way to do this?

i.e.:

```
SELECT example1, 
       example1a

FROM database 1 (if it exists) 

if not SELECT from database 2 (where it will exist)
```

Comment: where the DB / Table exists or that there is actually data in the table?

Comment: where there is actually the requested data in the table so if the selections aren't in db1 then look in db2

Comment: is this column by column or the entire dataset?

Comment: column by column.  An idea i came up with below - except it only returns ~ 700 lines, guessing because its not a UNION ALL?

Comment: SELECT TOP 1000 MATERIAL_NUMBER, 
    SALES_ORDER_NUMBER,
    REQ_CAT,
    PLANT,
    REQUESTED_DELIV_DATE

FROM   VW_ARUN_NORM_NEW

WHERE REQ_CAT LIKE '%1000%' 
OR    REQ_CAT LIKE '%2000%'

UNION 

SELECT TOP 1000 MATERIAL, 
    SALES_ORDER_NUMBER, 
    REQUIREMENT_CATEGORY,
    PLANT_CODE,
    REQUESTED_DELIVERY_DATE
    

FROM  VW_MRP_ALLOCATION

WHERE REQUIREMENT_CATEGORY LIKE '%5000%'

Comment: so basically if the requirement category is 1000 or 2000 look in the first table, if the stock category is 5000 look in the second table - sorry for the confusion

Comment: Well the union seems to be like a good idea... what's wrong with that? Or is this going to be a parameter?

Comment: more of a parameter (always take from DB1 if the stock category is in first list of selected values, if in second list of value(s) look in db2 always) - i am thinking the if exists below might be best will give it a shot. thanx for all the help

Comment: well it is either a parameter or it isn't. sorry, it's hard to follow you.

Comment: apologies yes it is a parameter - no coffee yet today lol thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is column by column basis you can use this most likely.

```
SELECT 
   coalesce(db1.example1,db2.example1), 
   coalesce(db1.example1a, db2.example1a)
FROM 
   database1 db1
FULL OUTER JOIN
   database2 db2 on
   db1.id = db2.id
```

If you are wanting to choose one or the other, you can use `exists()`

```
if exists(select 1 from VW_ARUN_NORM_NEW WHERE REQ_CAT LIKE '%1000%' R REQ_CAT LIKE '%2000%')
begin
    SELECT TOP  
        MATERIAL_NUMBER, 
        SALES_ORDER_NUMBER, 
        REQ_CAT, 
        PLANT, 
        REQUESTED_DELIV_DATE 
    FROM VW_ARUN_NORM_NEW 
    WHERE 
        REQ_CAT LIKE '%1000%' 
        OR REQ_CAT LIKE '%2000%' 
end
else
begin
    SELECT
        MATERIAL, 
        SALES_ORDER_NUMBER, 
        REQUIREMENT_CATEGORY, 
        PLANT_CODE, 
        REQUESTED_DELIVERY_DATE 
    FROM 
        VW_MRP_ALLOCATION 
    WHERE 
        REQUIREMENT_CATEGORY LIKE '%5000%'
end
```

Comment: I think this is down the right path, the only issue I see is that the second table has the same values but w/ slightly different field names...

Comment: i.e MATERIAL_NUMBER in table 1 vs MATERIAL in table 2

Comment: for which part? The coalesce version or the exists version?

Comment: are you querying this from an application or is this static code or? Explain the business case.

Comment: my tables is what I was referencing - they contain many fields w/ the same data but sometimes the field names are different.  So for both examples it seems that could cause issues?

Comment: Static code.  The issue is we have two data sets (tables) one contains only wholesale data and the second contains both wholesale AND retail data.  If the data is in the first table we want to go with that, if it isn't then we want to default to the second table which means it is retail - the confusing part for me is the different field names

Comment: The field names are irrelevant here. See the edit to if exists, but a union would be best here... it literally does exactly what you want..

Comment: you are correct - thank you so much one question, how to order by when the field names are different in a union?  Seems to not like that action?

Comment: In a union the first tables column names will be used so order by any column in the first table

Answer (score 1):

`ISNULL()` from an `OUTER JOIN` of the two tables is probably the best way.

Answer (score 0):

you could use if exists clause example

IF EXISTS (select example1 from database1)
begin

--do something

end
else
begin
--do another query
end

or you can check if the table exists:

(select top 1 name from sys.tables where name = 'ACTIVSOC2')

but when you select the table of the query must exists.

Hope you help